# active record_query to mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, mongoid

I want change this query:

```
messages = messages.where("name like :search or category like :search", search: "%#{params[:sSearch]}%")
```

to `mongoid` query.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Mongoid 2.x:

```
messages = messages.any_of({ name:     /#{params[:sSearch]}/ }, 
                           { category: /#{params[:sSearch]}/ })
```